# Python - Excel: Finding the first empty row in a column

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

working from my last question I've managed to get a good chunk of the way to get my system finished. Of course I've run across a problem.

I basically have a program that plays a game. Every correct answer adds 10 to the global variable 'points'. Then I want to add 'points' into an excel spreadsheet.

This is where I get very stuck. I'm running XLRD-0.8.0, XLUTILS-1.4.1 and XLWT-0.7.5.

Of course I've looked up different things but they don't seem to work for me.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
 import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, string, xlwt, xlrd, xlutils, socket


 points = 0

 def Uploadpoints(wbname):

     global points 
     wb = xlrd.open_workbook(wbname)

     # CODE TO FIND FIRST EMPTY CELL IN COLUMN 1 GOES HERE

     wb.write(row,0,points)
     wb.save()

 Uploadpoints('workbook1.xls')
```

I thought of doing something like this but I'm not sure how I would go about it so I post pseudo-code.

Define worksheet: `ws = 'sheet 1'` [Done]

Define column: `col = 0 [column A]` [Done]

Search for first row in col that is empty: ??? [Not Done]

Define first row that is empty as row: `row =`????? [Not Done]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Excel on the machine which will be running this game? If so might as well use `win32com` and use Excel itself to do this if this is causing problems. It's beautifully easy with that: `Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A"))`.

Comment: Yes Excel is on the machine. I'm not familiar with win32com, what would need to be changed / done to the code then?

Comment: Never used `xlwt` and `xlrd`, so hard to say. The general framework would stay the same, you'd just tell Excel to do the things you need it to do. Have a look here to judge it roughly: http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269583/appending-a-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-new-sheet-to-multiple-spreadsheets-using-pyth/21270641#21270641) a few days ago is very relelvant.

Basically whats going wrong is that `xlrd` and `xlwt` are different modules with different objects.  The object you read in with `xlrd.open_workbook()` **IS NOT** the same object which `xlwt` knows how to write to

To get around this, theres the copy function in `xlutils`.

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
import os

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(name) 

# Code to find the last open cell

wb = copy(wb)   #This is the important line!

sheet = wb.get_sheet(num)  #num is the index of the sheet you want to edit
sheet.write(whatever you want to write)

wb.save(name)
```

Comment: Hey I've got this; http://gyazo.com/caaf1ada6a60fc95032234ea15e2072c... but I'm getting the AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write' error message

Comment: @user3191879, how silly of me, you can't write to workbooks, see my update

Comment: wooooow I'm an idiot to not realise that xD Thanks for the save feature.

Comment: Well tbh, this was more asking how to get the first empty row number in a column :s We just kinda got side tracked.

Comment: Holy hell, my bad. Well as long as you got it working!

Comment: @user3191879, pnuts' comment reminded me, if you figure out the answer to your question, its generally good form to post it on here so other people can figure it out