# Find Next Empty Cell in Row Using XLRD/XLWT

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I have a workbook that I update each day with some data. I use a robot to collect that data, and now I need to dump it into that workbook each day. What I need to know is how to find the next available cell in which I can put the data. I don't want to overwrite old data.

For example I have:

A  B  C

1 x  x  x

2 x  x  x

3

I need to enter the data into row 3. The function from XLWT requires a row number and a column letter:
write(r, c, , )

So I need to set r & c to the next available cell. Would anyone happen to know a good way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in VBA/Excel, or Python?  What have you tried so far (post any code/formulas)?

Comment: Python, I haven't tried anything yet, I just need to know a simple formula to locate the next empty cell using Python.

Comment: Have you looked through these [Google results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=next+empty+cell+using+Python)?  Or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293968/python-excel-finding-the-first-empty-row-in-a-column)?

Comment: You can do it easily using `openpyxl` if you wish.